# Text Formula String Concatenation - Omit Trailing Comma

Tags: formula, formula-field, fields

**Scenario** :  I have 7 checkbox fields. For example say it is `Sunday`, `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday`, `Friday`, and `Saturday`. In Formula field I want to display all that are **true** as **comma separated text** in order from `Sunday` thru `Saturday`.

For example:

> Sunday - True
>   Friday - True

Formula Field should be - `Sunday, Friday`.

I tried below formula for concatenating but comma's are coming extra if any one of the field is false.

```
IF( Sunday__c = true, 'Sunday', '') + ','+
IF( Monday__c= true , 'Monday', '')+ ','+ 
IF( Tuesday__c= true , 'Tuesday', '')+ ','+ 
IF( Wednesday__c= true , 'Wednesday', '')+ ','+ 
IF( Thursday__c= true , 'Thursday', '')+ ','+
IF( Friday__c= true , 'Friday', '')+ ','+ 
IF( Saturday__c= true , 'Saturday', '')
```

Note : I don't want to go for trigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is how far you have to go to implement formula here. I'm doubtful its compile size will be under the limit, but I haven't checked.

```
IF(Sunday__c, 'Sunday' & IF(
    OR(Monday__c, Tuesday__c, Wednesday__c, Thursday__c, Friday__c, Saturday__c), ',', ''
), '') &
IF(Monday__c, 'Monday' & IF(
    OR(Tuesday__c, Wednesday__c, Thursday__c, Friday__c, Saturday__c), ',', ''
), '') &
IF(Tuesday__c, 'Tuesday' & IF(
    OR(Wednesday__c, Thursday__c, Friday__c, Saturday__c), ',', ''
), '') &
IF(Wednesday__c, 'Wednesday' & IF(
    OR(Thursday__c, Friday__c, Saturday__c), ',', ''
), '') &
IF(Thursday__c, 'Thursday' & IF(
    OR(Friday__c, Saturday__c), ',', ''
), '') &
IF(Friday__c, 'Friday' & IF(Saturday__c, ',', ''), '') &
IF(Saturday__c, 'Saturday', '')
```

---

A couple notes:

- You don't need to check `Checkbox__c = true` for a checkbox in a formula. Just use `Checkbox__c`.
- The proper string [concatenation operator](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#Concatenate) is a single ampersand (`&`).

Answer (score 6):

@AdrianLarson I used your suggestion for a similar solution and it worked for a year or so, until I was asked to include more Checkboxes (12 in all) in the formula, then I got:

> **Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (5,713 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters.**

I found a simpler solution. Include the ", " in each result, then add a period to the end of your IF statements. Wrap the code with `SUBSTITUTE` to replace ", ." with null in order to remove the trailing comma at the end of your text

```
SUBSTITUTE(
IF( Sunday__c, 'Sunday, ','') &
IF( Monday__c, 'Monday, ','') &
IF( Tuesday__c, 'Tuesday, ','') &
IF( Wednesday__c, 'Wednesday, ','') &
IF( Thursday__c, 'Thursday, ','') &
IF( Friday__c, 'Friday, ','') &
IF( Saturday__c, 'Saturday, ','') &
'.'),
', .', NULL)
```

Comment: Clever. Nice optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following logic -

```
IF( Sunday__c , 'Sunday ', '') + 
IF( Sunday__c & Monday__c , ', Monday', IF( Monday__c , 'Monday', '') ) +
IF (Tuesday__c & (Sunday__c OR Monday__c ), ', Tuesday' , IF(Tuesday__c , 'Tuesday', '') )+
So on...
```

This will add the commas only when it has any former value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: They are checkbox and it will be in the order they are written. That should not be a problem as in first condition you are checking if any previous checkbox is true then add comma, else simply add a Text without comma.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the `SUBSTITUTE` function to break repeated commas down to single commas, and then use the `MID` function to get rid of the leading and trailing commas:

```
MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(','&IF(Sunday__c,'Sunday','')&','&IF(Monday__c,'Monday','')&','&IF(Tuesday__c,'Tuesday','')&','&IF(Wednesday__c,'Wednesday','')&','&IF(Thursday__c,'Thursday','')&','&IF(Friday__c,'Friday','')&','&IF(Saturday__c,'Saturday','')&',',",,",","),",,",","),",,",","),2,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(','&IF(Sunday__c,'Sunday','')&','&IF(Monday__c,'Monday','')&','&IF(Tuesday__c,'Tuesday','')&','&IF(Wednesday__c,'Wednesday','')&','&IF(Thursday__c,'Thursday','')&','&IF(Friday__c,'Friday','')&','&IF(Saturday__c,'Saturday','')&',',",,",","),",,",","),",,",","))-2)
```

Comment: Don't you still need to reference the checkbox fields somewhere?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I hadn't gotten all of the details worked out when I did the first post. This should work though.